# Tabular Dynamic vectors

Tags: graphics3d, dynamic

Writing:

```
vp = Options[ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t}, {t, -5, 5}], ViewPoint][[1, 2]];
ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t}, {t, -5, 5}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]]
Dynamic[vp]
```

I get:

[image]

and by rotating the mouse the box changes the vector components in real time.

Unfortunately I can not figure out how to store those vectors in a matrix at each rotation made with the mouse.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the second argument of [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) to specify a function that is executed every time the value is changed:

```
hist = {};
vp = Options[ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t}, {t, -5, 5}], ViewPoint][[1, 2]];
ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t}, {t, -5, 5}, 
 ViewPoint ->Dynamic[vp, {Automatic, AppendTo[hist, #] &}]]
Dynamic[vp]
Dynamic[hist]
```

Now you can e.g. make an animation showing the states of the viewpoint:

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t}, {t, -5, 5}, ViewPoint -> hist[[v]]], {v, 1, Length@hist, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that it seems to evaluate the function twice each time you rotate the plot, each time with a slightly different value. (But that should be more or less eay to filter out.)

Comment: `(AppendTo[hist, #]; #) &` -- Does it accomplish anything for this function $f_{end}$ to return its argument?

Comment: @jjc385 No, I forgot to remove it after trying to find a way around the "two entries per change" issue. Updated the answer now, thanks.