# Rotating 3D graphics under program control

Tags: graphics3d, animation

With the following code

```
A = {{2.53237`, -1.39681`, 1.75671`}, {2.89875`, -0.411846`, 1.69636`}, 
     {2.89008`, -0.12331`, 1.75562`}, {3.01636`, 0.369294`, 1.48836`}, 
     {2.92773`, 0.985344`, 1.38112`}, {2.37448`, 2.07486`, 1.22752`}, 
     {1.59398`, 2.61631`, 1.43672`}, {0.810986`, 2.93926`, 1.46732`}, 
     {-0.417625`, 3.02086`, 1.46629`}, {-2.03506`, 2.17147`,1.61036`}, 
     {-2.91503`, 0.562121`, 1.62377`}, {-3.14816`, -0.441141`, 1.15952`}, 
     {-2.85433`, -1.66821`, 0.721034`}, {-1.88754`, -2.54601`, 1.18532`}, 
     {0.0116145`, -3.00769`, 1.55038`}, {0.999672`, -2.88571`, 1.45717`}, 
     {2.27014`, -2.12282`,1.33795`}, {2.39526`, -1.82074`, 1.54843`}, 
     {2.20699`, -2.14913`, 1.40016`}};

frames = 
  Table[
     ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t}, {t, -5, 5}, ViewPoint -> A[[a]]], 
     {a, 1, Length[A]}];

Export["trial.gif", frames, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞, "DisplayDurations" -> 1];
```

I get

[image]

where I matched the matrix `A` beforehand as recommended [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155969/tabular-dynamic-vectors).

What I would like to do now is to write an A-like matrix using a function so that the base plane is always horizontal and rotation is more homogeneous. The problem is that I have no idea what function to write. Ideas?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528).

Comment: Why not $a[\theta] = \{ 5 \cos (\theta), 5 \sin (\theta), 5 \}$?  This keeps the $z$ height constant and rotates the viewpoint in a circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You are using `ViewPoint` and if you would read docs thoroughly you'd see just the example you need in Applications section. The only thing I added is `AnimationRate->.01` that makes it very smooth.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewPoint.html

```
Animate[
    With[
        {v=RotationTransform[θ,{0,0,1}][{3,0,3}]},
        Row[{
            Graphics3D[{
                    Sphere[],Cuboid[],Red,PointSize[Large],
                    Point[v],Line[{v,{0,0,0}}],FaceForm[],
                    EdgeForm[Black],Cuboid[{-1,-1,-1},{1,1,1}]},
                PlotRange->3,BoxStyle->Gray,ImageSize->300],

            Graphics3D[{Sphere[],Cuboid[]},
                ViewPoint->v,SphericalRegion->True,ImageSize->300]}]],

{θ,0,2Pi},AnimationRunning->False,AnimationRate->.01]
```

To make GIF replace `Animate` with `Table` with small enough step to make GIF smooth (see top image):

```
frames=Table[
    With[
        {v=RotationTransform[θ,{0,0,1}][{3,0,3}]},
        Row[{
            Graphics3D[{
                    Sphere[],Cuboid[],Red,PointSize[Large],
                    Point[v],Line[{v,{0,0,0}}],FaceForm[],
                    EdgeForm[Black],Cuboid[{-1,-1,-1},{1,1,1}]},
                PlotRange->3,BoxStyle->Gray,ImageSize->300],

            Graphics3D[{Sphere[],Cuboid[]},
                ViewPoint->v,SphericalRegion->True,ImageSize->300]}]],

{θ,0,2Pi,.1}];

Export["frames.gif",frames]
```